# The optimized way to find the top k leading candidates from a unsorted hash map in python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, complexity

I need to write a method that will accept a timestamp and takes an array of votes, I need to return the `k` leading candidates with that timestamp. I came up with the following solution,

Here is the input to the methods:

```
votes = [{'candidate':'a', 'timestamp':2},{'candidate':'c', 'timestamp': 5},{'candidate':'c', 'timestamp': 12}]

timestamp = 5

k = 5
```

And the method to solve the problem,

```
def leading_candidates(votes, timestamp,k):

    candidates = {}
    leading_candidates = []

    for vote in votes:
        if vote['timestamp'] <= timestamp:
            if vote['candidate'] not in candidates:
                candidates[vote['candidate']] = 1
            else:
                candidates[vote['candidate']] += 1

    sorted_votes = sorted(candidates.values())[:k]

    for candidate in candidates:
        if candidates[candidate] in sorted_votes:
            leading_candidates.append(candidate)

    return leading_candidates    

print(leading_candidates(votes, timestamp, 2))
```

As you can see the second solution has a time complexity of \$O(k\,n)\$ where k is the time it takes to find the index in the leading candidates sorted array, In the worst case, it can be \$O(n^2)\$ and because of sorting it may be at least \$O(n\,\log n)\$.

Is there any way we can make it work with \$O(n)\$?

Comment: You already know that everything in sorted_votes is in candidates.  Why not "for sorted_votes" k times instead of "for candidates"?

Comment: @FrankMerrow Yes, but how efficient it is to find the key of particular value in the hash table?

Comment: Is there any other thing I can do to change the time taken.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. What is `timestamp duration`?

Comment: @greybeard It's 5, I added the inputs passed to the methods above, I just want to improve the method for the asymptotic conditions, In the extream conditions is it possible to get the O(n) result? I am using hashmap if we use any other data structure is there any improvement can be made on the time complexity?

Comment: (I do not want to know one/the value to use: I have no idea how to interpret it just from the problem description. I think one timestamp to mark one point in time, a *duration* could be specified by two *timestamp*s. Then, there is *before* and *after*.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, you want to count something and afterwards get the top `k`? That sounds like a job for [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)!

```
from collections import Counter

def leading_candidates(votes, timestamp, k):
    vote_counts = Counter(vote['candidate']
                          for vote in votes
                          if vote['timestamp'] <= timestamp)
    return [candidate[0] for candidate in vote_counts.most_common(k)]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(leading_candidates(votes, timestamp, 2))
```

This way you don't need to special case a candidate not yet having received a vote (something you could have also done with a `collections.defaultdict(int)`). And it is \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$.

Also note that if `k` is large, the line `if candidates[candidate] in sorted_votes` will become slow, as it is a linear scan. At the same time, you can iterate over the keys and values of a dictionary at the same time with `candidates.items()`, so you don't need to do `candidates[candidate]`.

Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which recommends using spaces after commas, which you forgot to do before `k` in the function signature.

You should always guard your code with an [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to allow importing from the script without running it.

Comment: `Counter.most_common()` uses a heap so it is O(k log h), where h is the total number of candidates (e.g., the size of the heap).  Of course for most uses, neither k nor h are large.

Comment: @RootTwo True. And `log h < n` and `k` is constant. But filling the Counter is still `O(n)`.

Comment: @RootTwo Yup, `Counter.most_common()` uses a heap; more specifically, it uses `heapq.nlargest()`. Which according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23038826 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/33644135 it actually has a time complexity of O(h log k), where h is the total number of candidates.

Answer (score 0):

It took some time but finally, I understood how we can solve this in `O (n)`.

Since the vote counts are Integers we can use bucket sort or in the worst case, we can use radix sort to sort the leading candidates and the resulting time complexity will be `O(n)`.